# Do the halakhot relating to stealing apply to people’s chokhmah / daas too?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing

Shalom.

I have been wondering if it is considered theft / stealing / robbery if one tries to acquire another’s chokhmah / daas without being honest about what one is doing. E.g. Asking questions with the wholly selfish motive of acquiring chokhmah / daas from a person. An example: one is desirous for chokhmah / daas and treats another person’s store of chokhmah / daas as a well to take from, so to speak, without regard for a person’s feelings. I suppose what I am asking is if a person’s knowledge etc. should be treated as their property, like any other property, and thus whether the halakhot relating to property apply here.

I am aware that such actions are not loving one’s fellow as oneself. But is this kind of thing considered stealing / robbery? Have any commentators addressed this matter?

Many thanks.

EDIT - a more tangible example provided here, in response to a query:

Jim knows that chokhmah / daas preserves life. He thus sets about acquiring it wherever he can. He shares lunch with Bob and makes an effort to extract all the chokhmah / daas he can from Bob in the time he has with him. He does not tell Bob that this is his intention. His pursuit of chokhmah / daas here is general, not pertaining to any particular problem or issue. His motive is also completely selfish.

I have been informed, since the original posting, that this is geneivat daas. Is it some other type of theft as well?

Comment: Shalom @Rabbi Kaii - I’ll edit for clarity :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. May I ask, if someone has a fire and you light your candle on it, is that stealing?

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - I agree; the general thrust of Mishlei is that chokhmah is ‘there for the taking’ - my concern was that this thrust is referring to books / things on the open market, rather than flesh and blood (?)

Comment: @TomW they didn't have many books back then. There was no market of educational literature

Comment: Shalom @Double AA - not trying to start a fight here :) but did not Shelomo Ha-Melech say ‘there is no end to the making of books’ (in Koheleth)?

Comment: @TomW are you aware of the concept of gneivas daas?

Comment: @Dov - shalom; I am - my guess is that this would apply here in that one does not make one’s intention plain, and thus acquires through deception. My concern was whether this is actual theft / robbery of property as well (?)

Comment: Why would you think that such deception is not robbery? The name itself intimates as much. See famously the Tosefta Bava Kamma 7:3 - https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Bava_Kamma.7.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en which lists it as one of the 7 types of thievery and writes - "שכל הגונב דעת הבריות נקרא גנב" "That anyone who (lit.) steals knowledge (i.e. deceives a person) - we call a thief"

Comment: @Dov I find it hard to view the examples in the question as genevat daat.

Comment: @Dov - that’s brilliant, thanks :) Put as answer and I will accept. Blessings.

Comment: @TomW I guess I was wrong!

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - only just seen your objection - I’m open to correction! :)

Comment: @TomW I am still a bit confused by the question. Can you give a practical example? "Bob knows that Jim has knowledge that can help him sell books better, and he wants that knowledge but he doesn't want Jim to know that he is seeking that knowledge, so he asks him indirect questions"? Something like that (but flesh it out more, explain exactly why he doesn't want Jim to know and if it will affect Jim in any way etc)

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - edited for clarity :)

Comment: @TomW I still want to push a bit, hope you don't mind. I would imagine that if Jim is asking Bob questions and Bob thinks that Jim is showing interest in Bob himself, but Jim is not at all interested in Bob himself, but is using the fact that Bob thinks that to be more open with him and tell him things he wouldn't otherwise tell him, that would be quite deceptive and could be considered genevat daat. Does that match your case? Or is that stretching it too far? Genevat daat must involve some form of trickery, can't just be a withholding of parev information afaik

Comment: If not, it sounds mostly like you are asking if it's ok to be selfish about acquiring wisdom in order to be a wiser, holier person? Have you read Mesilat Yisharim yet? Especially the chapters on cleanliness? I recommended it to you a while ago and I feel it is a good fit to the type of questions you ask

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - yes, I’ve been studying Mesillat Yesharim - will go back to the cleanliness section :) As for the example - you matched the case I am concerned about :) Do you think we could be talking about some kind of theft alongside geneivat daas here? T

Comment: @TomW the way this was taught to me was "when you use one candle to light another candle, that doesn't snuff the first candle out"

Comment: @יהשע ק - many thanks. Have noticed that this question was confused from the beginning. I may edit again for clarity, unless anyone objects. Blessings.